# Add constraint between NSScrollView content and outside object

Tags: macos, cocoa, autolayout, nsscrollview

How do you make an object outside of a scroll view lock onto an object within a scroll view using Auto Layout constraints?

The intent of the code below is to make the box object on the right move up with the bottom half of the scroll view content.

Instead, it starts in the right place, but doesn't move with the scroll view content.

AppDelegate.swift:

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!


    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        window.contentViewController = ViewController(nibName: "View", bundle: nil)
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }


}
```

ViewController.swift:

```
import Cocoa


class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var view1: NSView!
    @IBOutlet weak var view2: NSView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        view1.colorBackground(NSColor.red)
        view2.colorBackground(NSColor.blue)
    }
}



extension NSView {

    func colorBackground(_ color: NSColor) {
        wantsLayer = true
        layer?.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
    }
}
```

View.xib:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.Cocoa.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="14460.31" targetRuntime="MacOSX.Cocoa" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" customObjectInstantitationMethod="direct">
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.CocoaPlugin" version="14460.31"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <customObject id="-2" userLabel="File's Owner" customClass="ViewController" customModule="Test" customModuleProvider="target">
            <connections>
                <outlet property="view" destination="c22-O7-iKe" id="Yxc-sQ-AW4"/>
                <outlet property="view1" destination="8x7-dp-Hsw" id="evk-7F-37Z"/>
                <outlet property="view2" destination="f8D-v7-oc2" id="BgB-Fo-M7R"/>
            </connections>
        </customObject>
        <customObject id="-1" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="FirstResponder"/>
        <customObject id="-3" userLabel="Application" customClass="NSObject"/>
        <customView id="c22-O7-iKe">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="500" height="200"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMinY="YES"/>
            <subviews>
                <scrollView horizontalLineScroll="10" horizontalPageScroll="10" verticalLineScroll="10" verticalPageScroll="10" usesPredominantAxisScrolling="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="agq-bZ-fEr">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="400" height="200"/>
                    <clipView key="contentView" id="iYq-AW-6CU">
                        <rect key="frame" x="1" y="1" width="398" height="198"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <view translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Jr5-4g-mif">
                                <rect key="frame" x="-1" y="-201" width="400" height="400"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <stackView distribution="fillEqually" orientation="vertical" alignment="leading" spacing="0.0" horizontalStackHuggingPriority="249.99998474121094" verticalStackHuggingPriority="249.99998474121094" detachesHiddenViews="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="SyR-ko-zr4">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="400" height="400"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <customView translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="8x7-dp-Hsw">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="96" width="400" height="304"/>
                                            </customView>
                                            <customView translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="f8D-v7-oc2">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="400" height="96"/>
                                            </customView>
                                        </subviews>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstItem="f8D-v7-oc2" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="SyR-ko-zr4" secondAttribute="width" id="CUa-kB-FHn"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="8x7-dp-Hsw" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="SyR-ko-zr4" secondAttribute="width" id="Qeh-ci-tD8"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                        <visibilityPriorities>
                                            <integer value="1000"/>
                                            <integer value="1000"/>
                                        </visibilityPriorities>
                                        <customSpacing>
                                            <real value="3.4028234663852886e+38"/>
                                            <real value="3.4028234663852886e+38"/>
                                        </customSpacing>
                                    </stackView>
                                </subviews>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="SyR-ko-zr4" secondAttribute="trailing" id="071-Ds-bqi"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="SyR-ko-zr4" secondAttribute="bottom" id="GBW-oP-mbV"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="400" id="LG2-HP-nAB"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="SyR-ko-zr4" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="Jr5-4g-mif" secondAttribute="leading" id="xno-LJ-JNv"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="SyR-ko-zr4" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="Jr5-4g-mif" secondAttribute="top" id="y6g-52-NdQ"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </view>
                        </subviews>
                    </clipView>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstItem="Jr5-4g-mif" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="agq-bZ-fEr" secondAttribute="top" id="Ln7-Pi-szE"/>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="Jr5-4g-mif" secondAttribute="trailing" id="MO9-MN-kVt"/>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="200" id="l0n-gW-nUT"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="Jr5-4g-mif" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="agq-bZ-fEr" secondAttribute="leading" id="zbi-k8-oiU"/>
                    </constraints>
                    <scroller key="horizontalScroller" wantsLayer="YES" verticalHuggingPriority="750" horizontal="YES" id="gZP-Yp-TOe">
                        <rect key="frame" x="1" y="183" width="398" height="16"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                    </scroller>
                    <scroller key="verticalScroller" wantsLayer="YES" verticalHuggingPriority="750" doubleValue="1" horizontal="NO" id="Vcv-Oy-xXi">
                        <rect key="frame" x="383" y="1" width="16" height="198"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                    </scroller>
                </scrollView>
                <box boxType="custom" title="Box" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="wHO-ht-fwK">
                    <rect key="frame" x="450" y="-104" width="50" height="50"/>
                    <view key="contentView" id="7Ur-kr-AeI">
                        <rect key="frame" x="1" y="1" width="48" height="48"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                    </view>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="50" id="Tof-Kf-eC0"/>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="50" id="wqS-HE-kqB"/>
                    </constraints>
                    <color key="fillColor" red="1" green="0.3294117647" blue="0.3294117647" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                </box>
            </subviews>
            <constraints>
                <constraint firstItem="agq-bZ-fEr" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="c22-O7-iKe" secondAttribute="top" id="CrV-le-r8T"/>
                <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="wHO-ht-fwK" secondAttribute="trailing" id="Tas-pu-9sK"/>
                <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="agq-bZ-fEr" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="100" id="VWL-ze-Lbx"/>
                <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="agq-bZ-fEr" secondAttribute="bottom" id="gPO-Wu-Czj"/>
                <constraint firstItem="wHO-ht-fwK" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="f8D-v7-oc2" secondAttribute="top" id="qgy-WE-2Sh"/>
                <constraint firstItem="agq-bZ-fEr" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="c22-O7-iKe" secondAttribute="leading" id="y6u-QG-JtA"/>
            </constraints>
        </customView>
    </objects>
</document>
```

Comment: I can't tell from this XML what you're trying to do, but just a guess: scrolling isn't, by itself, something that would normally change or invalidate a layout. So you may need to add an observer that manually invalidates the layout whenever the scroll view scrolls. Probably the easiest way to do this is observe frame (origin) changes of the document view.

Comment: James Bucanek is right. I would suggest making the object part of the object in your scroll view.